# How to Match a Url Variable with php variable

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, url, popup

I implement a PHP code for fetch URL data or advertiser from database. These advertiser URL show in publisher site open in popup. I want before show URL publisher URL match some variable with code then show this site. Then publisher update is recode for his site name and userid name.

Like I said publisher have this type code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var uid = '123';
  var wid = '72';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://adscpm.net/pop.js"></script>
```

Now in this js link

```
http://adscpm.net/pop.js
```

Show some code with link

```
if(!uid)    
{var uid=0}
if(!wid){var wid=0}
var jsPopunder("http://adscpm.net/popup.php/"+uid+"/"+wid+")
```

Now actually I want when open http://adscpm.net/popup.php/uid=123/wid=72

its match `uid=123 and wid=72` to with `popup.php` code `uid=123 and wid=72`

when its match successfull then publisher update his record in database with uid=123

Answer (score 1):

You could send an request to the php file: popup.php?uid=123&wid=72.
Then you can read the values in php like:

```
$uid = $_GET['uid'];
$wid = $_GET['wid'];
```

Now you can update the database content with tha values and then redirect to the actual target page.

Comment: thanks for this .i asked one more thing how to open a url in phpcode like i get url random from database but when i run popup.php file its show url name only like http://www.adscpm.net. i want when open popup.php link i auto open link site which get from database

Comment: you can do a redirect with php using:
header("Location: URL");
@see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php